# git concurrency errors when running multiple jenkins jobs accessing/committing the same repo

Tags: git, continuous-integration, jenkins

I'm running multiple jobs in jenkins, they all work in the same repo but in different files, but sometimes it seems there are errors on race condition when pushing.

This happens when two jobs (or more) run at the same time. They pull from github repo, then  different files are change in each job, when is time to push and another job pushed before then the second job it will end up with push issues. Trying to fix this race condition I'm doing 'git pull' before commit, then I do 'git pull' once more in case another job updated the repo during that time, then I run 'git push' but sometimes another job pushed before I could push causing this the push to fail

Is there a way to only tell git to push a single file ? (I belive not but may be I'm wrong) or someone ran into this scenario and have a good way to avoid this race conditions?

This is the error I usually get:

```
git push 
Error reading response length from authentication socket.
To git@github.com:<my repo>.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:<my repo>.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes before pushing again.  See the 'Note about
fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are probably doing something wrong if you have your CI system committing and pushing to a git repository. But maybe you have a really, really good reason for doing it.

The only way to work around the problem is to prevent jobs that commit-and-push from running at the same time. You can do that by using a plugin like https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Throttle+Concurrent+Builds+Plugin or creating a slave with only 1 executor and restricting such jobs to run only on that slave.

Comment: why you say i should not commit and push from jenkins? I'm doing this as jenkins is building my packages and I have in some way increase the version numbers so the next run or whatever other job that needs to know the latest can get it from the repo.

Comment: If you need version numbers, you have two good alternatives that do not require Jenkins to commit: 1) the output from git describe or 2) Jenkins' own build numbers available from $BUILD_NUMBER environment variable. The trouble with having Jenkins commit are: 1) You need to grant Jenkins push permissions and 2) you could end up with an endless build loop where a new build gets triggered by Jenkins push.